# What to use instead of ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} from Gitlab CI for Docker Login?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am following [this tutorial](https://faun.pub/building-a-docker-image-with-gitlab-ci-and-net-core-8f59681a86c4) and they use

```
before_script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
```

I get this warning

```
WARNING! using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unecrypted in /root/.docker/config.json
```

`${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}` is a built in function in gitlab so I am not storing it anywhere. It seems this --password-stdin I got to read it in from a file or something?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the passsword as stdin:

```bash
before_script:
    - printf "%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} --password-stdin
```